# SQL - Dividing data from the same dataset with matching values in specific columns

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to find the proportion of females in a dataset that meet certain criteria: company id, job category, gender, timeframe, state id, and state kind. In order to do this, I have to divide the total # of females that meet this criteria by the total number of males and females that meet the criteria. 
I'm currently querying data to find the # females from company 20, in engineering, from all time, with kind and id = 0 and dividing it by the total # male and females that meet that criteria:

```
/* number of females in eng. jobs */
(SELECT 1.0*sum(hiring_sample_count) 
FROM metrics m
JOIN category c ON
m.job_id = c.job_id
AND m.company_id = 20
AND c.standard_job_cat = 'Engineering'
AND dimension_value = 'Female'
AND time_frame = 'ALLTIME'
AND state_kind = 0
AND state_item_id =0) /
/* number of m+f in eng */
(SELECT sum(hiring_sample_count) 
FROM metrics m
JOIN category c ON
m.job_id = c.job_id
AND m.company_id = 20
AND c.standard_job_cat = 'Engineering'
AND (dimension_value = 'Female' 
  OR dimension_value = 'Male')
AND time_frame = 'ALLTIME'
AND state_kind = 0
AND state_item_id =0))
```

The problem is that I want to calculate this for all the companies in the dataset across all job categories, kinds, and ids. I'm unsure of how to do this without specifying those myself, and was wondering if anyone could help. I am using SQLWorkbench which is a DBMS-independent, cross-platform SQL query tool. I would appreciate some help (I am not using TSQL or PL/pgSQL).

Apologies for the formatting as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to group by your list of columns that you'd like to identify the percentage of females, it will produce the counts separately. And the count itself is produced by conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
 m.company_id
,c.standard_job_cat
,time_frame
,state_kind
,state_item_id
,sum(case when dimension_value = 'Female' then hiring_sample_count else 0 end) as females
,sum(hiring_sample_count) as total
,1.0*sum(case when dimension_value = 'Female' then hiring_sample_count else 0 end)/sum(hiring_sample_count) as female_proportion
FROM metrics m
JOIN category c 
ON m.job_id = c.job_id
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5
ORDER BY 1,2,3,4,5;
```

`1.0*` is added to avoid integer division, and `females` and `total` columns are just given to perceive the context

Answer (score 0):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT AVG(CASE WHEN dimension_value = 'Female' THEN 1.0 ELSE 0.0 END) as female_proportion
FROM metrics m JOIN
     category c
     ON m.job_id = c.job_id
WHERE m.company_id = 20 AND
      c.standard_job_cat = 'Engineering' AND
      time_frame = 'ALLTIME' AND
      state_kind = 0 AND
      state_item_id = 0;
```